# Как проверить значение без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, input

[Пример JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7q4teys/)

```
<p class="question">2+2 ?</p>
Your answer:<input type="text" class="answer">
<input type="submit" class="checkAnswer" value="Check">
```

И таких блоков есть n-ое количество, у всех одинаковый класс. Как проверить значение, введенное в `input` не перезагружая страницу?
Была идея верный ответ записывать в  `div` с `display:none`, но у блоков одинаковые классы.
Помогите с концепцией:)

 *p.s. вопросы\ответы берутся с файла и генерируются на страницу с помощью php.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте jQuery, повесьте на этот инпут событие(ввод текста или фокус) и при каждом событии отправляйте ajax запрос на определенный url и там его обрабатывайте и возвращайте результат опять в js и потом выводите его.
Если опираться на ваш вариант в jsfiddle, то на кнопке отключите действие по умолчанию и например при правильном ответе подсвечивайте инпут зеленым а если не правильно то красным, тогда можно и без ajaxа.
Пример : берете свой кнопку jquery, $("#button").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); var data = $(".checkAnswer").val(); check(data)-(создаете отдельно функцию check с 1 аргументом и в ней проверяете уже что хотите) })
Это конечно кривой и самый просто вариант, но как вариант :)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX же. Как именно - другой вопрос. Если всё в рамках одного домена - то можно приюзать любой метод (хоть http://api.jquery.com/load/ ), если с разных - то JSONP.